# List all installed packages and their versions from the command line

Tags: miktex, installing

How can I [generate a list of all installed LaTeX packages, classes, and fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23840/8057) on the command line with MikTeX? Raw output is fine for my use case.

Related, with a TeXlive solution: [Diagnostics about LaTeX installation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/294149/8057).

Comment: I don't have MikTeX installed here, but according to the [documentation](http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/mpm.html) I think what you want is  `mpm --list | grep ^i`.

Comment: Related: [Packages included in default LaTeX distributions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37380/5764)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have not installed tools like `grep` on your windows computer (they are not installed with windows) you can use the old ms-dos pipe to create a file `test.txt` containing all installed packages with MiKTeX.

Use on your console/terminal:

```
mpm --list >test.txt
```

`--list` creates the list of installed packages, `>` directs the output in the file named afterwards `test.txt`.

If you have installed `cygwin` or other programs containing the unix-like tools like `grep` etc. you can use them of course.  My solution is working with "pure" windows ...

Comment: How to interpret the exported list? I see `i 00008     211297 a0poster` in a line, but the `a0poster` package is labeled as `Version 1.22b` when I look up for its package information. Is there a master list that can translate either `00008` or `221297` to be a specific version number? Thx!

Comment: @llinfeng please see my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/434205/16550 ...

Answer (score 3):

With `mpm` being moved to `miktex` the the following works:

```sh
miktex packages list  --template "{isInstalled} {id} {version}" | grep "^true" | sed -e "s/^true //"
```

See https://docs.miktex.org/manual/miktex-packages.html for other information you might want to put into the template.

Answer (score 0):

I am using MiKTeX 21.2 on Win 10. The previous command did not work for me. However, a similar command did. Specifically, starting miktex console and then
clicking on the packages tab, displayed  a long list with dates marked for those
packages that have been installed.
Strictly, speaking that list does not answer the original question. I have a hunch that it would not be hard to write a macro that would select those items on the list that have a date next to them. But this is only a hunch. Please let me know.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: A surprising problem in programming is that it's annoyingly difficult to transform text on your screen to text in a file.  MikTeX is pulling that information from somewhere; and it will be much easier to figure out where that information is than to parse a GUI.