# Understanding which packages have been installed on Windows

Tags: packages, miktex, windows

Referencing a previous question ([List all installed packages and their versions from the command line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294155/list-all-installed-packages-and-their-versions-from-the-command-line)) where the accepted solution to determining which packages have been installed on one's computer was to type the following in the command line:

```
mpm --list >test.txt
```

A snippet of the output file is reproduced below. Can someone please explain why some of these have 'i' and others have '-'?

```
- 00003     156041 lualatex-doc-de
- 00007     210562 lualatex-math
i 00039     507400 lualibs
- 00011     628914 luamesh
i 00008     251852 luamplib
i 00098    5295659 luaotfload
- 00006      41254 luapackageloader
- 00071     367828 luapersian
- 00006     278102 luasseq
```

This was done with Windows 10, MikTeX 2.9.6

Comment: AFAICS `--list` shows all available packages and only those marked with `i` are actually installed. The first number seems to be the number of files in the package and the second is the size in bytes.

Comment: The `mpm` docu at https://docs.miktex.org/manual/mpm.html mentions that the command to get a list of installed packages is `mpm --list | grep ^i` (but for that you need `grep` on your Windows machine), use `mpm --list | findstr /b i` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the command on the terminal/console

```
mpm --help
```

you will find the following explanaition:

```
 --list                               List the contents of the package
                                      database: for each package, print
                                      the installation status, the number
                                      of files, the size, and the name.
```

So the `i` means installed, `-` means not installed ...

Answer (score 0):

Check:
https://docs.miktex.org/manual/miktex-packages.html

I used the following command to list the packages and their versions, then I filtered only the installed ones with the grep utility (not installed on Windows on default, I used the git bash environment) and change the output to a .txt file.

> miktex packages list --template "{isInstalled}, {displayName},
> {version}" | grep ^true >isInstalledVersion.txt