# Understanding output from miktex packages list

Tags: miktex2.9

Following [Morty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/74295/morty)'s answer in [List all installed packages and their versions from the command line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294155/list-all-installed-packages-and-their-versions-from-the-command-line), I used

```
miktex packages list  --template "{isInstalled} {id} {version} {versionDate} {timePackaged}" > packages.txt
```

to tried to get the dates on which packages are packaged. I get, e.g., the following output:

```
true miktex-luatex-bin-x64-2.9 1.17.0  168331091
```

Is the last item, 168331091, the versionDate or timePackaged? Whichever it might be, what does it mean in terms of date or time?